# Batch file to delete folders older than 10 days in Windows 7

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file which should delete all subfolders of a folder which are older than 10 days, using Windows 7

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be clear: do you want to delete all folders which are older than 10 days, or a single folder *if* it's older than 10 days..?

Comment: delete all folders which are older than 10 days say for example : The folder which are older then 10 days under D:/Test should be get deleted not the one which are newly created..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete sub directories older than 30 days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419091/delete-sub-directories-older-than-30-days)

Comment: @nilesh, I think you should try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419091/delete-sub-directories-older-than-30-days/3419357#3419357) in particular, since you're on Win7 and therefore have `forfiles` available.

Comment: i Tried this FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd D:\Study" but getting below error "The directory is not empty" In path i gave D:/Study and study folder contains many folder from which i want to delete which are older then 10 days.. PLease help...

Comment: @BlorgBeard, also when i made study folder empty it deleted study folder. which is not my expected behaviour

Answer (score 54):

Adapted from [this answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419091/delete-sub-directories-older-than-30-days/3419357#3419357):

```
FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

You should run this command from within your `d:\study` folder. It will delete all subfolders which are older than 10 days.

The `/S /Q` after the `rd` makes it delete folders even if they are not empty, without prompting.

I suggest you put the above command into a .bat file, and save it as `d:\study\cleanup.bat`.

Comment: I used this command, and the folders have been deleted.
But I get an error: ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified.
I need to exit with error_level=0

Comment: I don't think you'd be needing FORFILES /S option as the subdirectories deletion will be through rd /S option.

Comment: Instead of running it from the current directory, it is always safer to use -P <directory_path> option with FORFILES. It will prevent accidental deletion in case you forget to change the directory.

Answer (score 11):

> FORFILES /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"

I could not get Blorgbeard's suggestion to work, but I was able to get it to work with RMDIR instead of RD:

> FORFILES /p N:\test /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE RMDIR /S /Q @path"

Since RMDIR won't delete folders that aren't empty so I also ended up using this code to delete the files that were over 10 days and then the folders that were over 10 days old.

> FOR /d %%K in ("n:\test*") DO (
>
> FOR /d %%J in ("%%K*") DO (
>
> FORFILES /P %%J /S /M *.* /D -10 /C "cmd /c del @file"
>
> )
>
> )
>
> FORFILES /p N:\test /S /D -10 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE RMDIR /S /Q @path"

I used this code to purge out the sub folders in the folders within test (example n:\test\abc\123 would get purged when empty, but n:\test\abc would not get purged

Answer (score 0):

If you want using it with parameter (ie. delete all subdirs under the given directory), then put this two lines into a *.bat or *.cmd file:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir %1 /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d" 2>nul && echo rmdir %%d
```

and add script-path to your PATH environment variable. In this case you can call your batch file from any location (I suppose UNC path should work, too).

Eg.:

```
YourBatchFileName c:\temp
```

(you may use quotation marks if needed)

will remove all empty subdirs under c:\temp folder

```
YourBatchFileName
```

will remove all empty subdirs under the current directory.