# How to remotely delete subfolders older than x days using windows command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

How can I remotely delete subfolders older than x days? Was able to find  a syntax like this, but it deletes all of the subfolders in xFOLDER. Any idea how I can modify the syntax and delete only subfolders in xFOLDER older than 7 days?

```
FOR /D %i IN (\\IP ADDRESS\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\FOLDERC\FOLDERD\xFOLDER\*) DO RD /S /Q "%i"
DEL /Q \\IP ADDRESS\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\FOLDERC\FOLDERD\xFOLDER\*.*
```

Comment: Look at the FORFILES command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: @Squashman tried FORFILES. But it doesnt work for UNC paths. I'll be remotely deleting files.

Comment: @user2784400 then use PUSHD.

Comment: If `pushd` does not work directly you can try to map with `net use` first

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497211/batch-file-to-delete-folders-older-than-10-days-in-windows-7) resembles yours, and has answers you should find useful.

Comment: Tried PUSHD, but it does not delete the folders older than 7 days, it loops through the subfolders and deletes the file older than 7 days, Any idea how to tweak this? : PushD "\\IP ADDRESS\FOLDERA\FOLDERB\FOLDERC\FOLDERD\xFOLDER\" &&("forfiles.exe" /s /m "*.*" /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @file") & PopD

Answer (score 0):

I manage to delete directory and subdirectory using this command

**RD** remove directory

**/S** use to remove directory tree

**/Q** quiet mode

> forfiles /D -7 /C "cmd /c rd /s /q @path"

change the code accordingly to your needs.