# Command Line 3 days rolling backup using RoboCopy

Tags: batch-file, command-line

what I would like to accomplish is have a three day rolling backup of the Source Folder, which will be modified every day. I want anything removed longer than 3 Days as worst case I will have to revert to the most recent backup but having that 3 Days allows me to revert back to a previous changes if need being.

What I have done in Command Line is as follows:

```
SET STAMP=%DATE:/=-% %TIME::=.%
SET SOURCE="C:\Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Source"
SET DEST="C:\Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Destination\%STAMP%"

robocopy %SOURCE% %DEST% /e

forfiles -p "C:\Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Destination\" -s -m *.* -d -3 -c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

I have timestamped and concatenated the FolderName and Current Date and Time.

However the bit I am struggling with his removing anything longer than 3 Days, currently the process is just copying, but what I need is a process to detect modified date or perhaps created date and remove directory anything greater than 3 days with the code I produced. The deleted command I have added above doesn't seem to do anything at all.

If anyone can help I will be most grateful.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: date and time format depends on locale/user settings, without knowing **your** format this is difficult. I'd suggest to choose `yyyyMMddHHmmss` which is alphabetically sortable and you can use a `for /f` parsing dir output and skip the 3 newest.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this:

```
SET STAMP=%DATE:/=-% %TIME::=.%
SET SOURCE="C:\Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Source"
SET DEST="C:\Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Destination\%STAMP%"

REM Set Robocopy to only retry once after waiting 1 second; copy all
REM file attributes, security, etc; and create a log file in the 
REM temp folder with the same name as the date.
robocopy %SOURCE% %DEST% /e /r:1 /w:1 /COPYALL /LOG:%TEMP%\%STAMP%.LOG

C:
CD \Users\PersonA\Documents\Test\Destination\
REM Recursively and quietly delete all directories older than
REM 3 days
FORFILES /S /D -3 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

This is extrapolated from the answer given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497211/batch-file-to-delete-folders-older-than-10-days-in-windows-7).

Comment: Thank You, I think it may have worked, copy wasn't working and not sure why, when I removed /COPYALL with /MIR it did the trick. I Just need to test it with one day now by changing it to -1 and test it tomorrow. Is there anyway to fudge the Modified or Created on Windows Attributes to test it on the same day? Thank you

Comment: You could use Nirsoft's Bulk File Changer - https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html - to change the created date of a folder.