# How to delete all empty folders which are older than 2 days?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I make a Script which deletes all empty Folders with Subfolders in a Path.
Now i have to make, if a folder was created 2 days ago and its empty it should be deleted with the other empty folders that are older than 2 Days.And if not it should be not deleted.
And i also need/want to make that deleted Folder are written in a Log.
I made that with the 5 Filetypes but i dont know how this schould work with the Folders.

Im really new to Batch, so i dont know what i should do.
I checked Google but the Results did not match with my problem.
I hope someone can help me.

Here is my Code that i´ve written so far:

```
@echo off

::start path / Variables
set startdir="C:\Users" 
::Initialize the Variable
set /a loop=0
::Directory c:\temp\ will be created, if the folder not exists 
if not exist c:\temp\ md c:\temp\
::Create Logfile for Deleted Filetypes in C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt
echo ----------------------------------- >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt
echo Logfile from: %date% at %time% >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt
echo. >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt
::this 5 Filetypes are going to be deleted immediately
del C:\Users\Thumbs.db /f /q /s >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt
del C:\Users\desktop.ini /f /q /s >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt 
del C:\Users\*.DS_Store /f /q /s >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt 
del C:\Users\*._DS_Store /f /q /s >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt 
del C:\Users\*.desktop /f /q /s >> C:\Log\LOG_Useless_File_Killer.txt 
::Writes the directorys in c:\temp\tmp.txt. 
dir /AD /b /s %startdir% > c:\temp\tmp.txt
::at goto start it will be start again
:start
::the Variable %loop% is increased by 1  
set /a loop =%loop%+1
::at 5 --> goto exit
if %loop%==5 goto exit
::Under 5 --> goto start 
else goto start
::deletes every empty folder which is written in C:\temp\tmp.txt
for /F "delims=" %%i in (c:\temp\tmp.txt) do rd "%%i" 
::--> goto start and begins again 
goto start
::%loop% has reached 5 --> exit
:exit
::Console window will be closed 
exit

pause 

exit
```

Comment: Do you have searched already on Stack Overflow with search term `[batch-file] older days`? There are many similar questions like [Delete sub directories older than 30 days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419091/).

Comment: look for a free tool called delage32. We use it for similar purpose.

Comment: I forgott to say that i already testet delage32,forefiles and robocopy. But i never reached my goal..
I searched on StackOverflow but i dont know how i can put this in a If or For.. Because when the Directorys are older then 2 Days(Creationdate) the should be deleted.
And i dont know how to make this in a loop or if..

Comment: @AmiKego I recommend the site http://ss64.com/nt where you can find reference for many batch commands, including `if` and `for`.

Comment: For deleting folders, try this:FORFILES -p "<path>" /D -15 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" , /D is for number of days, you can play with command parameters to meet exact requirement

Answer (score 0):

[Pradeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153541/pradeep) is absolutely right about the best way to go is for files.

> For deleting folders, try this:
>   FORFILES -p "" /D -15 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
>   /D is for number of days, you can play with command parameters to meet exact requirement.

You can also use environment variables too so you can easily only delete files on the user that is currently logged on. For example, you can use `%HOMEPATH%\Desktop` to get to the desktop of the current user. More environment variables [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).