# Delete folder and files if the folder date is 30 days old

Tags: batch-file, backup

I have a bat script that I run every day
1) Creates a folder with todays date
2) Copies some files to the new folder

I want to make the script also delete the folder and all files in it if the folder is older than 30 days.

```
@echo off

echo  
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Daily script that backs ups important files
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------


echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Calcualtion of date
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%
set timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%


echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Make new Backup folder
md G:\IMS-%fullstamp%
md G:\Backup\IMS-%fullstamp%\Services



echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Copy files into backup folder
xcopy /s /y C:\Services G:\IMS-%fullstamp%\Services


echo ------------------------------------------------------------------
echo Delete old backup folders if older than 30 days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31529663/3074564).

> > For deleting folders, try this:FORFILES -p "" /D -15 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path" , /D is for number of days, you can play with command parameters to meet exact requirement
>
> You can also use environment variables too so you can easily only delete files on the user that is currently logged on. For example, you can use %HOMEPATH%\Desktop to get to the desktop of the current user. More environment variables [here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true).